# Remove highly correlated variable and keep the low correlated

Tags: r, function, subset, correlation

I have a dataset "rf1" of 845 features and 1052 rows and want to eliminate, in order to do ML, the highly correlated features.
I made this code but it shows me features and correlations without eliminate them...

```
`corr_simple<-function(rf1,sig=0.9)
{df_cor <- rf1 %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
df_cor <- df_cor %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)
corr<-cor(df_cor)
corr[lower.tri(corr,diag=TRUE)] <- NA 
corr[corr == 1] <- NA 
corr <- as.data.frame(as.table(corr))
corr <- na.omit(corr) 
corr <- subset(corr, abs(Freq) > sig) 
corr <- corr[order(-abs(corr$Freq)),] 
print(corr)
mtx_corr <- reshape2::acast(corr, Var1~Var2,value.var="Freq")}
corr_simple(rf1)`
```

here is the result but I want to eliminate the variables with a threshold of 0.9
[MY RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEBi8.png)

When I use functions found here like this one I have an error message like this :

```
`data<-data.frame(rf1)
cor_matrix <- cor(data)
cor_matrix_rm <- cor_matrix                 
cor_matrix_rm[upper.tri(cor_matrix_rm)] <- 0
diag(cor_matrix_rm) <- 0
cor_matrix_rm
data_new <- data[ , !apply(cor_matrix_rm, 2, function(x) any(x > 0.90))]
Error in [.data.frame(data, , !apply(cor_matrix_rm, 2, function(x) any(x >  : 
  undefined columns selected`
```

I searched and tried other solutions but always this problem...

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a loop.  Here's an example using `mtcars`. You set the threshold to `r_threshold` (.8 in the example below).  You loop over the columns of `mtcars`, each time removing the columns that have an absolute value of the correlation about the pre-defined threshold.  After the relevant columns have been removed, it moves on to the next column, leaving the ones that have not been removed in previous steps.  Notice that `cyl`, `disp` and `wt` have been removed (you can see this by the difference in the column names before and after the loop.

```r
data(mtcars)
colnames(mtcars)
#>  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
#> [11] "carb"

r_threshold <- .8
keep_going <- TRUE
i <- 1
while(keep_going){
  s <- seq(i+1, ncol(mtcars))
  r <- cor(mtcars[,s], mtcars[,i])
  if(any(abs(r) > r_threshold)){
    mtcars <- mtcars[, -s[which(abs(r) > r_threshold)]]
  }
  i <- i+1
  if(ncol(mtcars) <= i){
    keep_going <- FALSE
  }
}
colnames(mtcars)
#> [1] "mpg"  "hp"   "drat" "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but when I run the code I have another error : Error in if (any(abs(r) > r_threshold)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Are any of the correlations in your correlation matrix missing? Use `use="pair"` as an argument to `cor()` and that will use pairwise instead of list wise deletion, which should solve the problem.

Comment: it works thank you Dave !!! I'm sorry for the questions, I'm just a beginner learning the R language...